# Adding column dependent on other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks as follows:

```
touch_id      sequence_id      timestamp_event     x      y
-----------------------------------------------------------
1             1                500                 20     20
1             2                600                 40     40
1             2                700                 30     33
2             1                880                 33     0
2             1                900                 22     22
3             1                910                 1      1
3             1                920                 10     15
3             2                950                 15     15
```

On this dataframe I apply the following:

```
df= df_touch.groupby(["touch_id", "sequence_id"]).agg({
    'timestamp_event': 'mean',
    'x': 'mean',
    'y': 'mean',
}).reset_index()


touch_id      sequence_id      timestamp_event     x      y
-----------------------------------------------------------
1             1                500                 20     20
1             2                650                 35     36.5
2             1                890                 27.5   11
3             1                915                 5.5    8
3             2                950                 15     15
```

Now I would like to have an additional column `multi_seq` which is true when for the same `touch_id` several different `sequence_id` exist. That means the resulting table should be

```
touch_id      sequence_id      timestamp_event     x      y        multi_seq
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             1                500                 20     20       True
1             2                650                 35     36.5     True
2             1                890                 27.5   11       False
3             1                915                 5.5    8        True
3             2                950                 15     15       True
```

How can I create this additional column `multi_seq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, `transform` + `nunique`

```
df['multi_seq'] = df.groupby('touch_id').sequence_id.transform('nunique') > 1
```

---

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: sequence_id, dtype: bool
```